# Application was crashed in managedQuery line in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have coded an application that contains an list that present contact information.

Application code is as follow:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Cursor mCursor=getContacts();
        startManagingCursor(mCursor);
        ListAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                mCursor, new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private Cursor getContacts(){
        Uri uri= ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection=new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
        String selection=ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "='" + ("1") + "'";
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        String sortOrder=ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
        Cursor out=managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
        return out;
    }
}
```

but application was crashed at `managedQuery` line.

I add also `READ_CONTACTS` permission to the manifest file.

What is wrong?

**Edited:**

Here is logcat data:

> ```
> --------- beginning of crash
> ```
>
> 08-18 17:36:45.093 6464-6464/com.example.morteza.listactivitycursor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.morteza.listactivitycursor, PID: 6464
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.morteza.listactivitycursor/com.example.morteza.listactivitycursor.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{afac265 6464:com.example.morteza.listactivitycursor/u0a98} (pid=6464, uid=10098) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>        Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{afac265 6464:com.example.morteza.listactivitycursor/u0a98} (pid=6464, uid=10098) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
>           at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1942)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1910)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1860)
>           at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getContentProvider(IActivityManager.java:4181)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:5970)
>           at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2592)
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1828)
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:786)
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:752)
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:710)
>           at com.example.morteza.listactivitycursor.MainActivity.getContacts(MainActivity.java:35)
>           at com.example.morteza.listactivitycursor.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
>        Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProviderImpl(ActivityManagerService.java:12185)
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerService.java:12582)
>           at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:357)
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3288)
>           at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
>   08-18 17:36:45.112 6464-6464/com.example.morteza.listactivitycursor I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6464 SIG: 9

What is wrong?

Comment: add your error from logcat

Comment: Beyond that, `managedQuery()` has been deprecated for **seven years**.

Comment: Wow ... Realy @CommonsWare ?!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must get the user's permission. The manifest is not enough.  
Check this: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Change to this:

```
    private Cursor getContacts(){
       Uri uri= ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
       String[] projection=new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
       String selection=ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "= ?";
       String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { "1" };
       String sortOrder=ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
       Cursor out=getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
       return out;
   }
```

Comment: @Morteza.M do you get permission by the user?

Comment: Yeah ... by this: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>`

Comment: @Morteza.M this is not enough. You must get permission at runtime once and for all.

Comment: @mTac, how can I do this?

Comment: @mTac, that needs API level min 23. Is this Ok? Any problem in the future?

Comment: @Morteza.M No there is no problem. The runtime permissions are needed for newer android versions.